# Code for page access

Tags: 7, security

I would like to use PHP code in nodes of a specific content type. I can check the user's permission with the global `$user` if the user can access the node.

Is there any module to set view for created page content?
Is it secure to check page access with this code?

```
global $user;

// Check to see if $user has the administrator role.
if (in_array('administrator', array_values($user->roles))) {
  // Do something.
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking for a node access module. There are many of them, for example http://drupal.org/project/content_access (configure access with roles directly) or http://drupal.org/project/tac_lite (control access by adding special taxonomy terms) and many more.

For your second question, you should always define some permissions (with [hook_perm](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_perm/6) in D6, [hook_permission()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7) in D7) and then check that. That allows to configure through the UI, which roles have that permission and the code is not tied to your specific configuration.

Comment: if i use global $user it is secure?

Comment: Yes, it is secure.

Comment: Just make sure not to mess it up :)

Answer (score 1):

Usually, on Drupal you don't verify if the users has a specific role, but if they have  a specific permission; for example, instead of checking of the user has the administrator role, you check if the user has the permission of administrating nodes. This allows to add the permission to other roles without to modify the existing code.
Referring to a specific role is not generic enough to be used in a module that could be installed on different Drupal sites; in the case you want to verify if the users have one of specific roles, you should check each role, while with the permission you possibly check only one permission.

Apart from the modules reported by Berdir, if the content type is a book page, then you can use [Book access](http://drupal.org/projerct/book_access), which is specific for book pages, and allows to set the users who can move book pages between books.